# Use Selenium to enter search text into Google

Tags: python, selenium

I want to go to Google, and type in "Hello world" using Selenium + Python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Everything up until this part works fine. But now I'm having trouble understanding how I'd select their text field and enter text. The searchbar has an ID `#gbqfq`, but the below code returns an error.

```
driver.webElement('body', 'gbqfq')
```

Error:

`'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'webelement'`

Here are the docs:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Comment: Your error doesn't match your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way to find an Element. In your case, the easiest approach would be find_element_by_id. Your code would look like:

```
driver.find_element_by_id()
```

There are many other ways to find an element, such as find an element by Xpath, by CSS selector and etc.

I am not really sure why you had a "webElement" in your code, is it a typing mistake?